# Unresolved external symbol _glad_XXX

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

I am relatively new to C++ but I have a few years of java experience. I decided to try to make a game with C++, In contrast with the handful of games i have written in Java with lwjgl. 
I am having a linker issue with GLAD. I used to have an issue with GLFW as well, but after trying hours of setting changes it finally worked (not sure what fixed it). 
 Now I am only having the GLAD linker errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenGlTesting, Configuration: Debug Win32 - -----
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gladLoadGLLoader 
referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glad_glClear
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glad_glClearColor
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glad_glViewport
1>C:\Users\Andrew Neeley\source\repos\OpenGlTesting\Debug\OpenGlTesting.exe : 
fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenGlTesting.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have (to my knowledge) successfully linked the GLAD files with my project.

 Here's the code (and yes, this code is copied from a tutorial):

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably figured this out already, but just in case you haven't - the GLAD library has both a header file and a source file. So you'll need to add that source file (glad.c) to your project as well as referencing the header file (glad.h) from the rest of your code as you've already done. That should fix your linker errors, as the glad_ symbols you're looking for are in glad.c.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I already solved the issue and that was it. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: @AndrewN. if this is what solved your problem then accepting it is appropriate even if you found it on your own.

Comment: I didn't know that in C file should be added by the hand. I thought it happens automatically when the file is in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

"Unresolved External" is just a fancy way of saying that the linker was not able to find a definition for a function/class declaration.

This usually happens when you are using some third party's header files, but you haven't told the linker *where* to look for the correct ** obj** files.

I have personally never used Glad, but this may be due to the fact that you forgot to add a **.lib** or **.dll** file in your project.

I have an idea, that should do the trick:
Since you are using OpenGL and you don't have any dll or lib file, you should tell the linke to use **opengl32.lib** (it comes with VC++ by default)

Comment: That's why I asked this question. I HAVE linked opengl32.lib and GLAD doesn't have a .lib file.

Comment: This has been a pain since I first started learning C in 1990. It usually happened with third party libraries. Is there no way to tell the compiler to "List every file you used" so that the list of files can be provided along with the third party library.